# Adding SQLite driver files to java directory in on my mac?

Tags: java, macos, sqlite, classpath

I am a new mac user and was wondering how I can add a jar file (the SQLite **sqlite_jni.dll** and **sqlite.jar**) to the systems jre files? the windows equivalent for me was to go in to the java directory and place the files in the **bin** and **lib** folder.

thanks and sorry i didn't phrase the question a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Java on mac located in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/`, but I don't think it is a good place to add jar files. Just keep jars you need in classpath when you compile and/or run your application. Also, you can add `CLASSPATH` env variable in your `.bash_profile|.bashrc` which will point to the jars you need. But I recommend you to keep your settings locally for the application.